# How to make datepicker cell editable?

Tags: java, gwt, datepicker

I am using GWT datepicker cell in my celltable. Here onclick event and on enter event it popups datepicker and set the cell value to the date we have selected. Now i want to remove the selected date from cell and make the cell blank , any workaround for this?

**Edit:**

```
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, Date value, 
                             NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Date> valueUpdater) {
       super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
       if ("click".equals(event.getType())) 
       { 
           valueUpdater.update(null); 
       } 
 }
```

Comment: what you have tried..?

Comment: on delete event i tried to null the value of "valueUpdater" .. buts its not working

Comment: put your code that you have tried..

Comment: public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, Date value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Date> valueUpdater) {
   super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
   if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
   valueUpdater.update(null);
   }
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to delete a date from a table cell.

One way to do this is to modify the constructor of `DatePickerCell`and to add a button that clears the date.

First copy `com.google.gwt.cell.client.DatePickerCell` in your progect

Unfortunately the editors can't be modified and you have to copy the editor. (All members are private)

```
HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

Button button = new Button("Clear");
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    //@Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        // Remember the values before hiding the popup.
        Element cellParent = lastParent;
        Date oldValue = lastValue;
        Object key = lastKey;
        int index = lastIndex;
        int column = lastColumn;
        panel.hide();

        // Update the cell and value updater.
        Date date = null;
        setViewData(key, date);
        setValue(new Context(index, column, key), cellParent, oldValue);
        if (valueUpdater != null) {
          valueUpdater.update(date);
        }
    }
});

horizontalPanel.add(button);
```

Comment: What is the other way to do this?